# Use XSL param value in HTML attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, apache-cocoon

I have a form like the following

```
        <form method="get"  action="change"  target="frame">
            <select name="fill" >
                <option>red</option>
                <option>green</option>
                <option>yellow</option>
                <option>pink</option>                                   
            </select>

        <input type="submit" value="darstellen"/>
        </form>

        <iframe name="frame">

        </iframe>
```

I want the form to send the color to another XSL file that contains a rectangle.
So far the passing of the color to the other XSL file works but now I would like to dynamically change the fill color of the rectangle but using the passed parameter wont work.

```
<map:match pattern="change">

<map:generate src="square.svg"/>

<map:transform src="recchange.xsl">

    <map:parameter name="use-request-parameters" value="true"/>

</map:transform>

<map:serialize type="html"/>
```

This is my sitemap

```
<xsl:param name="fill"/>
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
    <body>

        <h2><xsl:value-of select="$fill"/></h2>
        <h1>testtest</h1>
        <svg>
              <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:$fill;stroke-width:3;stroke:red">
              </rect>
        </svg>
```

And this is what I tried so far. Does anybody have advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-value-templates) here, to evaluate the `$fill` variable and output its value directly in the attribute string

```
 <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:{$fill};stroke-width:3;stroke:red">
```

So, the curly braces represent the Attribute Value Template here.

Comment: Very simple answer and worked perfectly, thank you very much! :)